# CartoDB json to HTML Table using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, carto, table, json, jquery

I am trying to display the dataset inside the cartoDB as HTML table. When i give request to the postgre database  by SQL API, it is returning as the format (json) below in the snapshot. I want the returning dataset to be displayed as HTML table in the browser. I had tried with the below code but it is displaying table for `var myList=[{"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
                       {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "swimming"},
                       {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}];`

But its not displaying for the below format.

[image]

And code i had tried is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        data1 = "transit_point_region_1";
        json_link = 'http://development.localhost.lan:8080/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM ' + data1;
        var data = $.getJSON(json_link);
        // Builds the HTML Table out of data.
        function buildHtmlTable() {
            var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(data);
            for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
                var row$ = $('<tr/>');
                for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
                    var cellValue = data[i][columns[colIndex]];
                    if (cellValue === null) { cellValue = ""; }
                    row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
                }
                $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
            }
        }

    function addAllColumnHeaders(data). {
        var columnSet = [];
        var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
            var rowHash = data[i];
            for (var key in rowHash) {
                if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) === -1){
                    columnSet.push(key);
                    headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
                }
            }
        }
        $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);
        return columnSet;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="buildHtmlTable()">
    <table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here. First, the JSON object shown in your screenshot has a slightly different format than the one expected by your code. Notice that at the beginning, the first key is `rows`, which contains all the results as an array (in square brackets). You can extract the results in the format you need by assigning `data.rows` to a new variable (i.e. `new_data = data.rows` or the like).

Here is an example fiddle (forked from the answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table), which appears to be the source of your code):

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/ws5rL3vy/

It uses data in the same format as the object from your screenshot and shows that extracting the `rows` array allows the data to be used in the functions that follow.

The second issue is that `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous method and will not return data immediately. You should be using the [appropriate syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) if you want your data to be accessible to the rest of your code. Typically, this is done as a callback function within the `getJSON` function itself. Your `buildHtmlTable` function should look something like this:

```
function buildHtmlTable() {
    $.getJSON(json_link, function (result_data) {
        var data = result_data.rows;
        var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var row$ = $('<tr/>');
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
                var cellValue = data[i][columns[colIndex]];

                if (cellValue == null) {
                    cellValue = "";
                }

                row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
            }
            $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a fiddle using `getJSON` to grab a file from Dropbox, which contains the same data as in the previous example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/goe84e04/